# In Stripe Subscription, how do i implement a rollover monthly usage that is not consumed to the next month?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, rollover, stripes

I have a monthly plan that uses a fixed price as well as graduated pricing i.e., 50 units included per month and 10 cents per additional unit of usage. If a customer's usage is below 50 units I want to rollover the remaining included usage to next month.

How can i do that in Stripe Subscription?

Unable to find any instruction to setup rollover usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe does not have pre-built functionality for this type of scenario, if this is something that you would like to handle then you will need to build your own code/solution to do so.

To do so you will likely want a place to track the excess that is being rolled over from previous billing period, and then for future billing periods you would first deduct overages from that running balance before adding Usage Records to the Subscription Item to update its usage in Stripe, but exact implementation details will vary based on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, just need a small clarification -  so for the next billing cycle is there a way for me to accommodate that usage in any pricing model or i should skip sending those rolled over usage records to Stripe and only send the usage after finishing the rollover to start clean?

Comment: Stripe does not have any mechanisms for handling the concept of rolling over unused usage, so there is no way to provide that information to Stripe in a way that  will cause anything meaningful to be done with it. You will likely want to experiment and test to find the exact flow that fits your business requirements, but I think you will want to avoid sending Usage Records to Stripe unless the rolled over usage has been fully consumed. Sending Usage Records will impact the next Invoice that is generated, so if you don't need to increase the amount of that Invoice you don't need to send one.